# Ubuntu Jail FTP-User in /var/www/html with full permissions

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, permissions, sftp

On Ubuntu 18.x I want to block a user in the /var/www/ html directory

I created a user this way:

```
useradd ftpuser
passwd ftpuser
usermod -G www-data ftpuser
usermod -d /var/www/html ftpuser
chown ftpuser:www-data /var/www/html
```

Then in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
    Match User ftpuser
            ChrootDirectory /var/www/html
            PasswordAuthentication yes
            X11Forwarding no
            AllowTcpForwarding no
            ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Then:

```
chown root /var/www/*
chown root:root /var/www/html
chown ftpuser:www-data /var/www/html*
```

I connect and I'm stuck in the html folder. But I can not create and edit files.
I want to assign full permissions to the ftpuser without the ability to level up from the html folder.

After giving the command from this answer

[setfacl -m g:ftpuser:rwx /var/www/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925356/allow-full-permission-to-var-www-html)

I can not connect anymore.

```
Error: Network error: Software caused connection abort
Error: Unable to connect to the server
```

**EDIT**

```
ls -la /var/www/html

total 28
drwxr-xr-x 4 ftpuser www-data  4096 Mar  9 14:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root      4096 Mar  9 14:31 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ftpuser ftpuser      0 Mar  9 14:54 aa
drwx------ 2 ftpuser ftpuser   4096 Mar  9 14:52 .cache
drwx------ 3 ftpuser ftpuser   4096 Mar  9 14:52 .gnupg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root     10918 Mar  9 14:32 index.html
```

Comment: Could you run `ls -la /var/www/html` and [edit] your question to include the output? It would be useful to see the actual ownership & permissions on the html directory and any subdirectories that you want these users to be able to access.

Comment: No one knows how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
ChrootDirectory /var/www/html
...
ls -la /var/www/html
drwxr-xr-x 4 ftpuser www-data  4096 Mar  9 14:54 .
```

The SSH server [ChrootDirectory option](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory) requires that the chroot directory belong to root:

> **ChrootDirectory**
>   Specifies the pathname of a directory to chroot(2) to after authentication. **At session startup sshd(8) checks that all components of the pathname are root-owned directories which are not writable by any other user or group.**

If you want `/var/www/html` to be the chroot directory, then it has to be root-owned, and it can't be group- or world-writable. The html directory may contain files and subdirectories which are writable by other users, but not the html directory itself.

Depending on what's in the `/var/www` directory, you might be able to make it the chroot directory.

Alternately, you could create a new directory to act as the chroot directory, then use a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/198591/41659) to make /var/www/html accessible from within the chroot directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understood several things. Can you tell me how to create a directory that acts as a chroot directory and use a link to make / var / www / html accessible? Or a link that tells me how to do it?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, any idea ? :)